# The influence of negative feedback on input resistance and bandwidth

Tags: negative-feedback

I'm interested in how negative feedback affects bandwidth and the cutoff frequency.
Is the cutoff frequency always increased by (1-Ab) times?
fg_r = fgo*(1-Ab)?
Does the same apply to input resistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Negative feedback will increase the upper frequency limit of an amplifier (lowpass principle) by the factor **(1-loopgain)** with loop gain **LG=-Ao*B** (Ao=Gain without feedback and B=feedback factor)
- The input resistance will be modified by the **same factor (1-loop gain)**.

  Feedback as a **voltage**: Input resistance will **increase**;

  Feedback as a **current**: Input resistance will be **reduced**.

Comment: Changes in input resistance depend on the topology of the circuit. E.g. a non-inverting input of an op-amp, without feedback elements attached to it, has a resistance independent of any feedback. When feedback is fed to the inverting input (or equivalent), the input resistance can be kept constant by maintaining a fixed Thevenin equivalent resistance of the feedback network in spite of changing closed loop gain. It'd help to explain what topology exactly you have in mind when talking about input resistance.

Comment: I am confused about the first two lines of your comment. To make it clear: Do you agree that the input resistance at the non-inv. opamp input will increase when negative feedback is applied to the inv. input (classical non-inverting application)?